# Python 3 - ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with my Python 3 program. I use Mac OS X. This code is running properly.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#! python3
# sendDuesReminders.py - Sends emails based on payment status in spreadsheet.

import openpyxl, smtplib, sys


# Open the spreadsheet and get the latest dues status.
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('duesRecords.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

lastCol = sheet.max_column
latestMonth = sheet.cell(row=1, column=lastCol).value

# Check each member's payment status.
unpaidMembers = {}
for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=lastCol).value
if payment != 'zaplacone':
    name = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
    lastname = sheet.cell(row=r, column=3).value
    email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=4).value
    unpaidMembers[name] = email


# Log in to email account.
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.login('abc@abc.com', '1234')


# Send out reminder emails.
for name, email in unpaidMembers.items()
body = "Subject: %s - przypomnienie o platnosci raty za treningi GIT Parkour. " \
       "\n\nPrzypominamy o uregulowaniu wplaty za uczestnictwo: %s w treningach GIT Parkour w ." \
       "\n\nRecords show  that you have not paid dues for %s. Please make " \
       "this payment as soon as possible."%(latestMonth, name, latestMonth)
print('Sending email to %s...' % email)
sendmailStatus = smtpObj.sendmail('abc@abc.com', email, body)

if sendmailStatus != {}:
    print('There was a problem sending email to %s: %s' % (email,
    sendmailStatus))
smtpObj.quit()enter code here
```

Problems starts when I am trying to add next value to the for loop.

```
# Send out reminder emails.
for name, lastname, email in unpaidMembers.items()
body = "Subject: %s - przypomnienie o platnosci raty za treningi GIT Parkour. " \
       "\n\nPrzypominamy o uregulowaniu wplaty za uczestnictwo: %s %s w treningach GIT Parkour w ." \
       "\n\nRecords show  that you have not paid dues for %s. Please make " \
       "this payment as soon as possible."%(latestMonth, name, lastname, latestMonth)
print('Sending email to %s...' % email)
sendmailStatus = smtpObj.sendmail('abc@abc.com', email, body)
```

Terminal shows error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "sendDuesEmailReminder.py", line 44, in <module>
        for name, email, lastname in unpaidMembers.items():
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: This means function `unpaidMembers.items()` doesn't return 3 items in the form of a tuple. Try printing its value to know what type of return value you get: `print unpaidMembers.items()`

Comment: Your code does not fit your traceback. In the code the problem is corrected but there's the `:` missing.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to unpack a tuple containing two items into three distinct items. Like @CarlesMitjans said, try printing out the value returned by `unpaidMembers.items()`. You may have to do some additional processing to turn it into 3 items.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably want to assign the `lastname` you are reading out here

```
lastname = sheet.cell(row=r, column=3).value
```

to something; currently the program just forgets it

you could do that two lines after, like so

```
unpaidMembers[name] = lastname, email
```

your program will still crash at the same place, because `.items()` still won't give you 3-tuples but rather something that has this structure: `(name, (lastname, email))`

good news is, python can handle this

```
for name, (lastname, email) in unpaidMembers.items():
```

etc.

Answer (score 9):

**1. First should understand the error meaning**

Error `not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)` means:

a **2 part** tuple, but assign to **3 values**

and I have written demo code to show for you:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Function: Showing how to understand ValueError 'not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)'
# Author: Crifan Li
# Update: 20191212

def notEnoughUnpack():
    """Showing how to understand python error `not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`"""
    # a dict, which single key's value is two part tuple
    valueIsTwoPartTupleDict = {
        "name1": ("lastname1", "email1"),
        "name2": ("lastname2", "email2"),
    }

    # Test case 1: got value from key
    gotLastname, gotEmail = valueIsTwoPartTupleDict["name1"] # OK
    print("gotLastname=%s, gotEmail=%s" % (gotLastname, gotEmail))
    # gotLastname, gotEmail, gotOtherSomeValue = valueIsTwoPartTupleDict["name1"] # -> ValueError not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

    # Test case 2: got from dict.items()
    for eachKey, eachValues in valueIsTwoPartTupleDict.items():
        print("eachKey=%s, eachValues=%s" % (eachKey, eachValues))
    # same as following:
    # Background knowledge: each of dict.items() return (key, values)
    # here above eachValues is a tuple of two parts
    for eachKey, (eachValuePart1, eachValuePart2) in valueIsTwoPartTupleDict.items():
        print("eachKey=%s, eachValuePart1=%s, eachValuePart2=%s" % (eachKey, eachValuePart1, eachValuePart2))
    # but following:
    for eachKey, (eachValuePart1, eachValuePart2, eachValuePart3) in valueIsTwoPartTupleDict.items(): # will -> ValueError not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    notEnoughUnpack()
```

using `VSCode` debug effect:

[image: notEnoughUnpack CrifanLi]

**2. For your code**

```py
for name, email, lastname in unpaidMembers.items():
```

but error
`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`

means each item(a tuple value) in `unpaidMembers`, only have 1 parts:`email`, which corresponding above code

```py
    unpaidMembers[name] = email
```

so should change code to:

```py
for name, email in unpaidMembers.items():
```

to avoid error.

But obviously you expect extra `lastname`, so should change your above code to

```py
    unpaidMembers[name] = (email, lastname)
```

and better change to better syntax:

```py
for name, (email, lastname) in unpaidMembers.items():
```

then everything is OK and clear.

Answer (score 5):

In this line:

```
for name, email, lastname in unpaidMembers.items():
```

`unpaidMembers.items()` must have only two values per iteration.

Here is a small example to illustrate the problem:

This will work:

```
for alpha, beta, delta in [("first", "second", "third")]:
    print("alpha:", alpha, "beta:", beta, "delta:", delta)
```

This will fail, and is what your code does:

```
for alpha, beta, delta in [("first", "second")]:
    print("alpha:", alpha, "beta:", beta, "delta:", delta)
```

In this last example, what value in the list is assigned to `delta`? Nothing, There aren't enough values, and that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since `unpaidMembers` is a **dictionary** it always returns two values when called with `.items()` - (key, value). You may want to keep your data as a list of tuples `[(name, email, lastname), (name, email, lastname)..]`.

Answer (score 1):

ValueErrors :In Python, a value is the information that is stored within a certain object. To encounter a ValueError in Python means that is a problem with the content of the object you tried to assign the value to.

in your case name,lastname and email 3 parameters are there but unpaidmembers only contain 2 of them.

> **name, lastname, email in unpaidMembers.items()**
>   so you should refer data
>   or your code might be
>   **lastname, email in unpaidMembers.items()**
>   or
>   **name, email in unpaidMembers.items()**