# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2) - python/tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to understand some code implemented using the tensorflow framework on jupyter notebook, when I get the following error on running this cell. I do not understand the problem here and some clarification would be very helpful.

For reference, a training decoding layer is being created here in tensorflow.

Code:

```
   def decoding_layer_train(encoder_state, dec_cell, dec_embed_input, 
                         target_sequence_length, max_summary_length, 
                         output_layer, keep_prob):
    """
    Create a decoding layer for training
    :param encoder_state: Encoder State
    :param dec_cell: Decoder RNN Cell
    :param dec_embed_input: Decoder embedded input
    :param target_sequence_length: The lengths of each sequence in the target batch
    :param max_summary_length: The length of the longest sequence in the batch
    :param output_layer: Function to apply the output layer
    :param keep_prob: Dropout keep probability
    :return: BasicDecoderOutput containing training logits and sample_id
    """
    # TODO: Implement Function

    # Helper for the training process; used by Basic Decoder to read inputs
    training_helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(inputs=dec_embed_input,
                                                        sequence_length=target_sequence_length,
                                                        time_major=False)


    # Basic decoder
    training_decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(dec_cell,
                                                       training_helper,
                                                       encoder_state,
                                                        output_layer)


    # Performs dynamic decoding using the decoder
    training_decoder_output, final_state, final_sequence_lengths = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(training_decoder,
                                                                                                     impute_finished=True,
                                                                                                     maximum_iterations=max_summary_length)

    return training_decoder_output



"""
DON'T MODIFY ANYTHING IN THIS CELL THAT IS BELOW THIS LINE
"""



tests.test_decoding_layer_train(decoding_layer_train)enter code here
```

Error message (Screenshot):

[image: Screenshot detailing the error]

Comment: `tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(...)` What does you expect this to return? Can you try printing the value of this before assigning it to `training_decoder_output, final_state, final_sequence_lengths`

Comment: it expects a final output, final state and final sequence lengths as mentioned in the documentation here : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/dynamic_decode

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was using tensorflow 1.1, just had to change that to 1.2 and everything worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I just changed

```
training_decoder_output, final_state, final_sequence_lengths = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(training_decoder...
```

to

```
training_decoder_output, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(training_decoder...
```

and the tests passed on 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

"not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)", it means method is returning 2 values, whereas caller is expecting 3 values.

*training_decoder_output, final_state, final_sequence_lengths = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(training_decoder, impute_finished=True, maximum_iterations=max_summary_length)*

Return values expectations in above method is incorrect.
Refer doc "https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.seq2seq#Dynamic_Decoding" and serach "dynamic_decode", you will get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

have answered detail explanation for `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`, paste my code here:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Function: Showing how to understand ValueError 'not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)'
# Author: Crifan Li
# Update: 20191212

def notEnoughUnpack():
    """Showing how to understand python error `not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`"""
    # a dict, which single key's value is two part tuple
    valueIsTwoPartTupleDict = {
        "name1": ("lastname1", "email1"),
        "name2": ("lastname2", "email2"),
    }

    # Test case 1: got value from key
    gotLastname, gotEmail = valueIsTwoPartTupleDict["name1"] # OK
    print("gotLastname=%s, gotEmail=%s" % (gotLastname, gotEmail))
    # gotLastname, gotEmail, gotOtherSomeValue = valueIsTwoPartTupleDict["name1"] # -> ValueError not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

    # Test case 2: got from dict.items()
    for eachKey, eachValues in valueIsTwoPartTupleDict.items():
        print("eachKey=%s, eachValues=%s" % (eachKey, eachValues))
    # same as following:
    # Background knowledge: each of dict.items() return (key, values)
    # here above eachValues is a tuple of two parts
    for eachKey, (eachValuePart1, eachValuePart2) in valueIsTwoPartTupleDict.items():
        print("eachKey=%s, eachValuePart1=%s, eachValuePart2=%s" % (eachKey, eachValuePart1, eachValuePart2))
    # but following:
    for eachKey, (eachValuePart1, eachValuePart2, eachValuePart3) in valueIsTwoPartTupleDict.items(): # will -> ValueError not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    notEnoughUnpack()
```

more detailed explanation please refer [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259166/python-3-valueerror-not-enough-values-to-unpack-expected-3-got-2)