# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2) while implementing a blockchain

Tags: python, python-3.x, blockchain, valueerror

I'm using python 3.8.2 to implement a blockchain and getting a valueError while running my wallet.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 137, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 98, in get_balance
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Blockchain/transaction_block.py", line 159, in get_balance
    for addr, amt, inx in txn.inputs:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

The error, I think to my understanding, is specifically is in the transaction_block module's get_balance() function and transactions module's add_input() method.

transactions module:

```
class txn:
    inputs = None
    outputs = None
    signatures = None
    required = None 

    def __init__(self):
        self.inputs = []
        self.outputs = []
        self.signatures = []
        self.required = []

    def add_input(self, from_address, amount, index):
        self.inputs.append((from_address, amount, index))

    def add_output(self, to_address, amount):
        self.outputs.append((to_address, amount))
```

transaction_block module:

```
def get_balance (pu_key, last_block):
    this_block = last_block
    bal = 0.0
    while this_block != None:
        for txn in this_block.data:
            for addr, amt, inx in txn.inputs:
                if addr == pu_key:
                    bal = bal - amt
            for addr, amt in txn.outputs:
                if addr == pu_key:
                    bal = bal + amt
        this_block = this_block.previous_block
    return bal
```

While I tried searching for this error online and found some solutions ( [Python 3 - ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259166/python-3-valueerror-not-enough-values-to-unpack-expected-3-got-2?newreg=00ab49f97aae43bbbb23c950ca5ad579)) but they did not work for me completely. So please can anyone help me fix this?

P.S.: I'm new to posting on stackoverflow so if you have any suggestions to improve my question please do give them! Also I do not know if I should put the entire modules here for this question for understanding purposes but if you need that as well feel free to ask for it! I've not added them to make the question a little clutter free.

Answer (score 0):

`txn.inputs` returns 2 values not 3. 
You tried to unpack 3 values because your for loop has `for addr, amt, inx` while in reality `txn.inputs` doesn't include 3 values

Edit: I tried using your code and it works just fine for me. It seems that your `txn` is constructed the wrong way. Try printing `txn` to debug your error