Efficient parallelization of silhouette score calculation
I have a large dataset (2 million rows, 100 columns), and I need to perform clusterization. I used the elbow method to determine the optimal number of clusters. However, in order to get a more refined picture, I also need to calculate the silhouette scores for a range of n_clusters. I have access to a 36-CPU AWS machine, however I don't get a significant improvement from using that machine compared to a 8-CPU machine. So I was wondering how I could parallelize the computation.
This is the unparallelized code:
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score, silhouette_samples
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# Apply K-Means
kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters = 50, batch_size = 1000, random_state = 42)
kmeans.fit(data)
labels = kmeans.labels_

# Calculate silhouette score
score = silhouette_score(data, labels)

I tried using joblib's Parallel and delayed functions:
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples, silhouette_score
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import numpy as np


# Apply K-Means
kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters = 50, batch_size = 1000, random_state = 42)
kmeans.fit(data)
labels = kmeans.labels_

# Compute the average silhouette score for the current clustering
silhouette_values = Parallel(n_jobs = 36)(
    delayed(silhouette_samples)(data, labels)
)
average_silhouette_score = np.mean(silhouette_values)
score = average_silhouette_score

But this produces an error:
---> 18 silhouette_values = Parallel(n_jobs=4)(
     19     delayed(silhouette_samples)(selected_columns, labels)
     20 )


ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)

Any suggestions as to what could be done would be welcome

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259166/python-3-valueerror-not-enough-values-to-unpack-expected-3-got-2 maybe these helps a little

from the documentation: https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html it looks like the argument to Parallel(n_jobs = 36)() should be a generator
